# Non-symmetric non-positive matrix eigenvalues

Tags: matrices

basically I am wondering about how to determine, given a square nxn matrix non symmetric and non-positive, how to understand how many positive eigenvalues it has without calculating them.

Comment: Non symmetrical matrices have eigenvalues in the complex plane. Are you talking about the real part?

Comment: I would like to understand something more so yes.